# How to store the id of the image stored in other table in the users table in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I want my users to upload profile pictures while registration such that it's paths will be stored in `'images'` table having columns image_id, image_path and I want the value of the `image id` to be stored in the `'users'` table at the same time.

Anyone please help me to do it.

Comment: Wrong logic. If User has an image, than image belongs to the associated user. That means images table has `user_id` column.

Comment: @Levente, not necessarily. Your suggested DB structure is a one-to-many relationship (a user can have many images). But perhaps, the OP wants a user to have a single image only (because it's a profile pic!). Then, the OP suggested structure is a viable one to one relationship.

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Comment: Okay, gimme a few minutes to write an answer.

Comment: @Prateek, What do you mean, "please help me do it"? What have you tried so far? Dont expect anyone to write the whole thing for you. Try upwork or something, not SO!

Comment: You are right Sir but I have an another table where I have stored image_id with user_id. It will help me to store all my Images at one place and I can distinguish these as profile image, product image and shop image in the separate tables. I think you get my point @LeventeOtta

Comment: @Paras What if this project grows large and will it be necessary to expand it? Or if it is needed for another project? It's good to learn the usable logic at the beginning

Comment: How is a one to many relationship "usable logic" if the OP's use case requires a one to one relationship?

Comment: @Paras, You are right about the db structure. And I am very new to laravel, I can write this code using php and mysql but not in laravel. I have researched Google and SO for hours after that I have posted this question here.

Comment: @Prateek Sorry for late answer

Comment: @LeventeOtta, Thanks let me try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer to the original question:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$image = new UserImage(['file' => 'image.jpg', 'is_index' => true]);

$user->images()->associate($image);
$user->save();
```

Shortcut: `$user->images()->save($image);`

Documentation for [associating](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models).

## Requested Tutorial:

So we have a simple `users` table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And we have a simlpe `user_images` table:

```
Schema::create('user_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable(); // user id
    $table->string('file')->unique(); // File path
    $table->boolean('is_index')->default(false); // is it profile picture? you can call this whatever you want
    $table->softDeletes(); // 'deleted_at' column for archive
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`User` Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,
        SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the images for the user.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserImage::class);
    }

}
```

And the `UserImage` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class UserImage extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * All of the relationships to be touched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $touches = ['user'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'file',
        'is_index'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the image.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is how users have many images.

---

If you want retrieve an user all images in controller:

```
User::find(1)->images;
```

For example:

```
$user = User::find(1);
foreach($user->images as $images) {
    echo $user->file;
}
```

You can add scope to you `UserImage` model for easier get profile picture

```
public function scopeAvatar($query)
{
    $query->where('is_index', '=', '1')->first();
}
// Usage:
$user->image->avatar->file // Only the profile picture
```

Documentations:

- [One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- [One to Many (Invers)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)
- [Soft deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting)
- [Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/socialite#access-scopes)
- [Touches](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept your answer at that time. Nice Work. Will improve my question to make it more generalized.